# Preposition with years

Tags: preposition

I have encountered this sentence:

> Die Zeit der absoluten Monarchie ist seit der Französischen Revolution **von** 1789 vorbei.

The German prepositions are always confusing to me and this "von" didn't help much.
I know with years you don't use any preposition unless you write the word "Jahr" for example "im Jahr 1789". Please explain it to me

Comment: _"... you don't use any preposition unless you write the word "Jahr""_ That's obviously a wrong premise.

Comment: Yeah thanks man I wanted to make sure because there are always exceptions in languages.

Comment: Same in English, https://www.britannica.com/event/French-Revolution:
French Revolution, also called Revolution of 1789, revolutionary movement that shook France between 1787 and 1799 and reached its first climax there in 1789—hence the conventional term “Revolution of 1789,” denoting ...

Answer (score 3):

*Die Revolution von 1789* means exactly the same as "the 1789 revolution". There is no deeper logic behind this usage of "von", you just have to learn it. Note that "of" can be used in a similar way, e.g. "the great depression of 1929".

Comment: Oh right thanks a lot!

Comment: Ich denke schon, dass es sich hier um eine bestimmte Sorte von **von** handelt. ;-) Ich sehe dieses z.B. auch in *das Brot **von** gestern*, *die Zeitung **von** morgen* oder *deine Bemerkung **von** vorhin*. Ich kann es jetzt nicht genau benennen aber möglicherweise verbindet all diese Verwendungen die Herstellung eines zeitlichen Bezugs?

Comment: Aber im Zusammenhang mit Jahreszahlen nach dem Muster *von JJJJ* muss man es wahrscheinlich wirklich einfach wissen/lernen, da hast du recht.